# Is there a reliable source for APM distribution in leagues?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am wondering how I do APM / EPM wise compared to other players. The only source I found so far is this [Teamliquid poll](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=120988).

But I have some issues with this:

- It's very old
- It's a poll so everbody can cheat
- It's biased as only a certain kind of payers visit Teamliquid

I am searching for the APM or EPM distribution for the leagues.

Comment: Seriously, APM is just a lolstat. It's not about how fast your fingers are, but about how fast your brain can sort your gargantuan todo list out to tell your fingers what to do next.

Comment: This might be true, but still good gamer have beyond 150 APM. This is why I want to look at some kind of distribution to see if there is some kind of correlation.

Comment: This got too big for a comment, see my answer below.

Comment: On a related note, there is some data on APM for a collection of pros: www.razerzone.com/sc2/en/apm

Comment: APM/EPM matter: An interpretation of Day9's teaching: "Talking about 50-80 he meant that this is enough to not hold most players back until they reach very high level play and actually qualified it with "basically". 300 was about pros and high level play and that having 300 cannot hurt.
" [source](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=145494&currentpage=372#7422)

Comment: Remember you need a minimum of intentful (and not spammed) APM to achieve what you want. Thought experiment: 1v1 against your clone (who is capable of  1APM, or 400APM)

Comment: Actually that was the reasoning behind this question. I wanted to know if there is some kind of minimum requirement to get to a specific league.

Comment: with 50-80 relevent APM, you can get to masters. Then to break the top 8 and over, you have to up that to 150-200 at least. But until microing every unit in your army becomes a factor (which isn't really until high masters), 50-80 is more than enough.

I also wonder if that chart would be meaningful. I play people in diamond that have 300+ APM and they still get destroyed and I'm only around 100 APM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as heishe stated, you simply won't find global stats on APM, because most people don't care. The only people that could publish reliable data on the topic are Blizzard, and I have yet to hear if they care.

This is not meant as an insult, but only newbies seem to care about APM/EPM, probably because they see korean pros move their fingers so fast it's almost like you're watching an anime. I have 120 APM myself, and I'm a bronze player. I know other players in Bronze that have way above 250 APM. Similarly, I know a plat player who has the same APM as me.

It's a bit like saying whether a racing car can handle 4k or 6k RPM. Of course it relates, but there are more important factors for the car's performance on the track, of which the pilot's brain is not the least important. I'm not a mechanic, so please excuse any rampant mistakes in my analogy =)

The underlying truth about APM is *yes*, APM matters, but only once your brain is faster than your fingers, and you'll be low Master league by the time this happens.

Comment: Haven't played for months now, but before I stopped I was platinum with 80 APM (spiking to 120ish in emergencies) and no cheesing, just solid understanding of the game. I have replays with opponents in my league that had even less, though not much less, cause it can hardly go any lower :).

Comment: @Fadeaway: I am Diamond with 60 APM :) thats why I wanted to see other players in comparison. My Spikes are about 200.

Comment: The bronze with 250 APM probably spams all day long. The thing about APM is if you can macro super fast you won't need as high of an APM. Spamming a million times to move one unit will give you a high APM as well...

Answer (score 0):

Of course I can't guarantee this, but I can say with 90% certainty that you will not find such stats, simply because they're not of interest to many people (player skill depends on a ton more than APM), and also if you're looking for GSL stats, those replays aren't public.

However, if you want those stats on the MLG, IEM etc. tournaments and leagues, you could get them yourself by gathering up a lot of replays of the various events of those leagues and using [SC2Gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/) to look at the APM distribution of certain players.